# extjs 4 - How to add a different event listener for PropertyGrid? PropertyGrid's addListener/on function not executing

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

Apologies for the long title. Basically, I want to add a `keydown` event listener to my propertyGrid. I've been looking online for possible solutions but I haven't been lucky.

I have a property grid defined as such:

```
{
    xtype: 'propertygrid',
    x: 570,
    y: 210,
    id: 'pfGridPanelMode',
    itemId: 'pfGridPanelMode',
    maxWidth: 200,
    minWidth: 200,
    width: 200,
    frameHeader: false,
    header: false,
    title: 'Payment Mode',
    scroll: 'none',
    sealedColumns: true,
    sortableColumns: false,
    source: {
        Cash: '',
        Check: '',
        Total: ''
    }
}
```

I know I can use the `propertychange` event listener and get the `recordID` and the `newValue`. However, I want the keydown event so that when the user fills up the `Cash` and `Check` fields, I can update the `Total` field live.

I've checked the other event binding names and I saw `cellkeydown`, however, it does not seem to work when I added it in my controller as such:

```
onPropertygridCellkeydown: function(tableview, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts) {
            console.log("cell key down fired");

            console.log("cellIndex " + cellIndex);
            console.log("rowIndex " + rowIndex);

}
. . . . . . . 

"#pfGridPanelMode": {
            cellkeydown: this.onPropertygridCellkeydown
            //I have other event listeners here
 },
```

I've tried clicking and entering values in the cells but to no avail.

I then checked the extjs4 docs from sencha and I saw the [add listener method](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.property.Grid-method-addListener) of the grid panel. I tried the example of adding a `mouseover` listener but to no avail. I tried putting the code on the `beforerender` and the `afterrender` events like so:
(please note that this function is in my controller)

```
onPropertygridBeforeRender/onPropertygridAfterRender: function(component, eOpts) {
    var form = Ext.getCmp('processingFeeRecieptPanel');
    var receipt1 = form.child('#receipt1');
    var mode = receipt1.child('#pfGridPanelMode');

    mode.addListener("mouseover", this.onMouseOver, this);
    mode.on({
        mouseover: this.onMouseOver
    });
}
```

and I have the `onMouseOver` event like so:

```
onMouseOver: function() {
    console.log("on mouse over called");
}
```

However, that too does not work - the log does not show up.

Does anyone have a solution for this? I want a keydown listener so that the updates are live. I know I can use the `propertychange` listener but I am aiming for a better user experience overall.

Thank you for any help and sorry for the long post.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your grid:

```
listeners: {
    afterrender : function(grid) {
        grid.el.dom.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
            Ext.defer(function(){
                console.log(e.srcElement.value);
            },10);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Humm.. i guess its a Bug with Ext 4.2.1 and 4.2.2. I updated my solution with a not-so-elegant work around.

Comment: Sorry but I found a different solution and I forgot to put my answer here. I will try to check your edit and post feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I made it work. The basic idea is to make a textField inside the `source` using `sourceConfig` and the `editor` method. This textField is then given a listener for `keyup` event (or any event that you want). You can then do anything you want inside that listener. For my case, I called a controller to calculate a total value that I need.

Here is my `source`:

```
source: {
    "Cash": 0,
    "Check": 0,
    "Total": 0
}
```

Here's my `sourceConfig`:

```
sourceConfig: {
    Cash:{
        editor: Ext.create(
            'Ext.form.field.Text',
            {
                selectOnFocus: true,
                enableKeyEvents: true,
                listeners: {
                    keyup : function(textfield, e, eOpts) {
                        console.log("cash value change new value is = " + textfield.getValue());
                        myAppName.app.getController('PFReceipt').computeTotal('cash', textfield.getValue());

                    }
                }

            }

        ),
        type:'number'
    },
    Check:{
        editor: Ext.create(
            'Ext.form.field.Text',
            {
                selectOnFocus: true,
                enableKeyEvents: true,
                listeners: {
                    keyup : function(textfield, e, eOpts) {
                        console.log("cash value change new value is = " + textfield.getValue());
                        myAppName.app.getController('PFReceipt').computeTotal('check', textfield.getValue());

                    }
                }

            }

        ),
        type:'number'
    },

}
```